# How to hide the chat sidebar in Facebook automatically?

Tags: facebook

I am fine with the ticker (the small button down right). But when I am in Facebook, I have to tick it every time and then the chat sidebar hides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see today that if you hide the sidebar it sticks like that at the next FB visit.
So either Facebook changed back to how it was before or I didn't know that happens.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the chat automatically, then this most likely means you don't want to chat at the moment.

Select "Unavailable to chat", then hide the sidebar.

Any future requests to the Facebook homepage (whether you are logged out or not) will have the chat window closed.

Comment: no, I want to chat, it just that that sidebar bothers me. I think it was not before and made it now to pressure you to chat.

Comment: @Theta30 That does not really make sense if you think about it. If you want to chat and you don't see the sidebar, how will you click the users to chat with?

Comment: I can click the ticker. Then the sidebar appears and see who is online. Besides, they can contact me.